# Show that the polynomial $x^4+x+1$ is primitive over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, primitive-roots

I've been struggling for hours and so far have shown the polynomial is irreducible, $p(0) \neq 0$, and monic.

All there is left to prove is that the polynomial is of order $15$.

Then I can use a theorem.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: $\Phi_{15,F_2}(X)=X^8+X^7+X^5+X^4+X^3+X+1=(X^4+X+1)(X^4+X^3+1).$

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x)$, then in $\mathbb{F}_2$, we can write $$\alpha^4=\alpha+1.$$ Now possible orders for $\alpha$ are $1,3,5,15$. See if you can rule out the lower orders.

Comment: A brute force proof is a part of [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619). Proving primitivity doesn' t actually take that much because you only need to rule out five as a possible order. And the roots of unity of order five are the zeros of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.